# Parsing a long string to a LocalDate variable

Tags: java, date, datetime, localdate

I recently had the need to take an string and convert it to a LocalDate Variable in Java; I knew this was possible and easy, but here's what I didn't see:

**Context:** I'm using exiftool to extract the metadata from an image via a Java Runtime Execution.
The problem is that exiftool provides this next string:

```
2019:02:28 11:37:47-06:00
```

This isn't your normal Standard ISO Format (or atleast I think that it isn't). I don't know if this is using any already implemented formatting standard.
So, to fix my problem, I created the next code for manual parsing:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(VAR_WITH_STR_TO_CONVERT, formatter);
```

I think this is a good implementation for manual conversion, but this code generates this next exception:

```
> Text '2019:02:28 11:37:47-06:00' could not be parsed at index 19
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source)
```

I believe that the problem is the Format String that I provide to convert, but uppon checking the DateTimeFormatter Docs, I think I have the right string.

```
yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ssZ
```

I'm out of ideas, does anyone know the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** For time zone, use `XXX`, not `Z`, to parse a value like `-06:00`.

---

The documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), specifies:

> **Offset X and x:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters.
>
> - One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'.
> - Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'.
> - **Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.**
> - Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'.
> - **Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'.**
> - Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.
>
> **Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.**

> **Offset Z:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters.
>
> - *One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the offset is zero.*
> - Four letters outputs the full form of localized offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero.
> - **Five letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero, with colon. It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero.**
> - Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.

As you can see, you used 1 `Z`, which means `-0600`.

To parse a time zone with hours and minutes (optional seconds), *with* colons, you need one of the highlighted patterns:

```
XXX      UTC is `Z`.
XXXXX    UTC is `Z`. Optional seconds.
xxx      UTC is `+00:00`
xxxxx    UTC is `+00:00`. Optional seconds.
ZZZZZ    UTC is `Z`. Optional seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

> 2019:02:28 11:37:47-06:00
>
> This isn't your normal Standard ISO Format

Similar to ISO 8601:

- Replace the SPACE character in the middle with a `T` character.
- Replace the first two COLON characters with hyphens.

## String manipulation

You could do this by splitting the string on SPACE, replacing the first two colons in the first part, then stitch back together.

```
String input = "2019:02:28 11:37:47-06:00";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
String inputModified = parts[0].replace( ":" , "-" ) + "T" + parts[1] ;
```

## Formatting code: `xxxxx`

Or you could define a custom formatting pattern with a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object. Use five `x` code-characters for an offset of hour-minutes and optional seconds with COLON character delimiters.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu:MM:dd HH:mm:ssxxxxx") ;
```

See this formatter in [code running live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/XTFkWM).

## `OffsetDateTime`

> LocalDate.parse

No, first parse all of it, not just the date portion, just in case you may find that valuable at some point. Parse as an `OffsetDateTime` as your input indicates an offset-from-UTC (hours-minutes-seconds) but not a full time zone (`Continent/Region`).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Apparently you want the date-only portion, without the time-of-day and without the offset-from-UTC. Assuming you want the date as seen in that offset, simply call `toLocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2019-02-28

Or perhaps you want the date as seen elsewhere. Remember, for any given moment the date and time-of-day vary around the globe by time zone. It might be “tomorrow” in `Asia/Japan` while simultaneously “yesterday” in `America/Edmonton`.

## UTC

If you want the date as seen in UTC:

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
LocalDate ld = odtUTc.toLocalDate() ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Or perhaps you want the date as seen in a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Tip: If you can determine the source of the colons in the date portion, educate them about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Comment: "Fixing" the date string is not the right answer, when `DateTimeFormatter` can parse the value without fixing it. All it takes is the correct pattern string. Nothing in the question says it is *supposed* to be an ISO date string. OP is just acknowledging that OP doesn't believe is actually is one (which is correct). Fixing the date string just complicates and obscures the code.

Comment: @Andreas To each his/her own. When processing faulty/wacky data, I usually first cleanse before processing. Furthermore, the author the Question expressed an interest in ISO 8601, so I thought it helpful to make clear the differences between the input and the standard. Lastly, I took your comment to heart and added the necessary custom formatting pattern in a `DateTimeFormatter` with a live code example at IdeOne.com.

Comment: Most lenient pattern would be `XXXXX` or `ZZZZZ`, since that supports optional seconds and supports `Z` for UTC.